# Nixpkgs Overlays: Why are some non-overwritten attributes different between "super" and "self"?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

> **Background**
>
> When I've added the first [Overlay](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays) for Nixpkgs, I found out that a bunch of system utils got built for a different version:
>
> ```
> these derivations will be built:
>   /nix/store/028dqnwq36xja16gba3gckq5mcprpn06-postfix-main.cf.drv
>   /nix/store/b2sch2538ny2drdf9zzknf38grn8d8r3-pcre-8.42.drv
>   /nix/store/i1k9ksk32ca441zap40z3zddy7bhqx3n-zlib-1.2.11.drv
>   /nix/store/sypawsb3cwqnnhdl1barv2d8nyvbsxyv-coreutils-8.29.drv
>   /nix/store/xa4vnajxck2zgvjwp7l71lm11hqnz32r-findutils-4.6.0.drv
> ...
> ```
>
> which is time and space consuming. I tried to figure out what's going on then end up with this question.

### Summary

The idea of `self` and `super` of [overlays](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays) is that `self` is the accumulated result after all overlays have applied, while `super` is the result of applying the previous overlay.

I thought that an attribute that have not been touched by will be the same between `self` and `super`, but some are not.

```
let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {
    overlays = [
      # This overlay obtains self.bash and super.bash, and save them under the
      # attrs "bash-from-self" and "bash-from-super" for further examination
      (self: super: {
        bash-from-self = self.bash;
        bash-from-super = super.bash;
      })
    ];
  };
  # Retrieve bash-from-self (self.bash) and bash-from-super (super.bash)
  # from the overlayed nixpkgs
  inherit (nixpkgs) bash-from-self bash-from-super;
in {
  # Check if bash-from-self (self.bash) and bash-from-super (super.bash)
  # are same
  isBashSame = (bash-from-self == bash-from-super);
  inherit bash-from-self bash-from-super;
}
```

The above evaluates to:

```
{ isBashSame = false; 
  bash-from-self = «derivation /nix/store/zvy7mbpxqlplqpflqn5xk9szx25s4mhg-bash-4.4-p23.drv»;
  bash-from-super = «derivation /nix/store/2i91sj16snsphvjrbsa62z8m4zhs261c-bash-4.4-p23.drv»; }
```

Showing that `self.bash` and `super.bash` is not the same, even that the `bash` attribute isn't touched in any overlays. Why is this happening, or did have some concepts missing in mind?

---

### Details

#### More different attributes

Besides of `bash`, there're more attributes that are different:

```
let
  isAttrSame =
    attrName:
    let
      nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {
        overlays = [
          (_self: _super: { inherit _self _super; })
        ];
      };
      self = nixpkgs._self."${attrName}";
      super = nixpkgs._super."${attrName}";
      isSame = self == super;
    in
      isSame
  ;
in {
  coreutils = isAttrSame "coreutils";
  bash = isAttrSame "bash";
  zsh = isAttrSame "zsh";
  zlib = isAttrSame "zlib";
  stdenv = isAttrSame "stdenv";
  findutils = isAttrSame "findutils";
  gnutar = isAttrSame "gnutar";
  gcc = isAttrSame "gcc";
}
```

```
{
  bash = false;
  coreutils = false;
  findutils = false;
  gcc = true;
  gnutar = true;
  stdenv = true;
  zlib = false;
  zsh = true;
}
```

#### The builder of `self.bash` is `super.bash`?

```
let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {
    overlays = [
      (self: super: {
        bash-from-self = self.bash;
        bash-from-super = super.bash;
      })
    ];
  };
  inherit (nixpkgs) bash-from-self bash-from-super;
in {
  bash-from-self-builder = bash-from-self.drvAttrs.builder;
  bash-from-super-builder = bash-from-super.drvAttrs.builder;
  bash-from-self-outPath = bash-from-self.outPath;
  bash-from-super-outPath = bash-from-super.outPath;
}
```

```
{ bash-from-self-builder = "/nix/store/2ws9cmamvr7xyvdg4d2nnd1bmr1zjrrq-bootstrap-tools/bin/bash";
  bash-from-self-outPath = "/nix/store/06z61jbgs0vkw4i9cqqf9yl7zsfkkhw2-bash-4.4-p23";
  bash-from-super-builder = "/nix/store/06z61jbgs0vkw4i9cqqf9yl7zsfkkhw2-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash";
  bash-from-super-outPath = "/nix/store/2avim7j13k75k26w18g6br8gai869nm9-bash-4.4-p23"; }
```

`bash-from-self-outPath` is the `bash-from-super-builder` (`06z61...khw2-bash-4.4-p23`).

So `super.bash` uses `self.bash` to build itself, producing another bash (`2avim...9nm9-bash-4.4-p23`)?

`bootstrap-tools/bash` --builds--> `self.bash` --builds--> `super.bash`

#### Why this is a problem

I want some of my packages defined in an overlay to depend on `bash`, `coreutils` and stuff. I want to use the original version of them provided directly from `<nixpkgs>`, not those may be overwritten by later overlays. So, in this case, seems that I should choose `super.*` instead of `self.*` to be the dependencies.

But some `super.stuff` is not the original `nixpkgs.stuff`, this causes rebuilding them as there's no binary cache and is a waste of disk space. And `self.stuff` can probably be overwritten by later overlays. What can I do?

Comment: It seems to have to do with stdenvOverrides, https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/ea863cd334be044aee28e77ff4446f16063ec30e/pkgs/top-level/stage.nix#L190